# How to retrieve multiple spaces from a string

Tags: c#

I have this method:

```
        public static string ReplaceVarReferences(string input,char open, char close)
        {
            string inner = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (input[i] == open)
                {
                    i++;
                    string varInner = "";
                    while (input[i] != close)
                    {                        
                        varInner += input[i];
                        i++;                        
                    }
                    inner += GetVariable(varInner);
                }
                else
                {
                    inner += input[i];
                }
            }
            return inner;
        }
```

and this memory allocation and retrieval methods:

```
        public static Dictionary<string, string> memory = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public static string GetVariable(string key)
        {
            if (memory.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return memory[key];
            }
            else
            {
                return key;
            }
        }
        public static void SetVariable(string key, string value)
        {
            if (memory.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                memory[key] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                memory.Add(key, value);
            }
        }
```

I want to to return a string with the 'ReplaceVarReferences' method and return a string with multiple spaces like this:

this code is from my interpreter and not real code.

```
var a = hello world;
print(variable a =     {a})
```

the 'ReplaceVarReferences' method should be able to return this with multiple spaces:

```
"variable a =     hello world"
```

but instead, it returns:

```
"variable a = hello world"
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: How about replace `inner += GetVariable(varInner);` with `inner += GetVariable(varInner) + "spaces";`

Comment: it's not working, it still gives the same result.

Comment: Ok, I was looking at the wrong place I figured it out thank you.

Comment: @TyperMan1133 - Please post your answer.

Comment: I will mark as correct after 2 days from now, sorry for not clarifying the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I looked at the wrong place I have another method that had the problem:

```
public static string GetNested(string Open, string Close, List<string> t, ref int i)
        {
            string inner = "";
            int nested = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                if (i < t.Count - 1)
                {
                    i++;
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t[i]))
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < t[i].Length; x++)
                        {
                            inner += " ";
                        }
                    }
                    else if (t[i] == Close)
                    {
                        nested--;
                        if (nested > 0)
                        {
                            inner += t[i];
                        }
                    }
                    else if (t[i] == Open)
                    {
                        if (nested > 0)
                        {
                            inner += t[i];
                        }
                        nested++;
                    }                    
                    else
                    {
                        inner += t[i];
                    }
                    if (nested == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return inner;
        }
```

i did not include:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t[i]))
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < t[i].Length; x++)
                        {
                            inner += " ";
                        }
                    }
```

and it resulted in the spaces being dumped when retrieving the nested string.